# If player is not holding the ladder then it should not jump twice

Tags: unity, 2d

I am using Unity2d and I am stuck with a problem. I made the new layer for ground and ladder and added `OverlapCircle` and make double jump script for the player, so if the player touches the ground or ladder it jump twice (on pressing the `jump` key).  If the player presses the `W` key in front of ladder then it should hold the ladder and the player can move up and down. Then if the player presses jump then the players jump from the ladder, we can jump single or twice from the ladder according to our intention.

I want it so that if the player presses the `W` key and holds the ladder then only he can jump and if he only touches touches the ladder and `W` key is not pressed the `jump` key should not work.

Below is the player script:

```
[SerializeField] 
[SerializeField] float _xSpeed = 1f;
[SerializeField] float _ySpeed = 1f;
[SerializeField] float _jumpForce = 1f;
[SerializeField] float _distance;
[SerializeField] LayerMask _ladderLayer;
private float _horizontalMovement;
private float _verticalMovement;
private Rigidbody2D _rb;
private bool _isClimbing;
private bool _isMovingHorizontal = true;

[SerializeField] Transform _groundPos;
[SerializeField] float _checkRadius;
[SerializeField] LayerMask _groundLayer;
private bool _isGrounded;

// ExtraJump
private int _extraJumps;
[SerializeField] int _extraJumpValue = 1;

void Start()
{
    _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    _extraJumps = _extraJumpValue; 
}

void Update()
{
    _horizontalMovement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    _verticalMovement = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");       
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if(_isMovingHorizontal)
    {
        _rb.velocity = new Vector2( _horizontalMovement * _xSpeed,_rb.velocity.y);
    }
    
    _isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(_groundPos.position,_checkRadius,_groundLayer);

    if(_isGrounded == true)
    {
        _extraJumps = _extraJumpValue;
    }
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && _extraJumps > 0)
    {
        _rb.velocity = new Vector2(_rb.velocity.x,_jumpForce);
        _extraJumps --;
    }
    else if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && _extraJumps == 0 && _isGrounded == true)
    {
        _rb.velocity = new Vector2(_rb.velocity.x,_jumpForce);
    }

    RaycastHit2D hitLadder = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position,Vector2.up,_distance,_ladderLayer);

    if(hitLadder.collider == true) 
    {
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            _isClimbing = true;
            _rb.gravityScale = 0;
        }
        else if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)) 
        {
            _isClimbing = false;
        }       
    }

    if(_isClimbing == true && hitLadder.collider == true)
    {            
        _rb.velocity = new Vector2(_rb.velocity.x,_verticalMovement * 
        _ySpeed);
    }
    else
    {
        _rb.gravityScale = 1;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Your code does not contain any check if your character holds the ladder at all. That might be start implementing.

Comment: Sry...I am still learning, can you explain through my script where i can check if my player holds the ladder

Comment: What do you mean by holding? That your player is climbing it up? Or can he move the ladder over his head carrying it around?

Comment: To sum it up: You want to have the possibility to jump if the player climbs the ladder but not having the option when he hits the ladder while jumping, correct? Can the player climb the ladder if he hits it while jumping? Or can climb ladder only initiated at the bottom/ top of it while grounded.

Comment: yes...suppose( point A and B) and there is ladder between them....if i jump from point A to point B while  in air and touches the ladder then the player jump in the air(as the jump key is pressed) i dont want that

Comment: `else if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && _extraJumps == 0 && _isGrounded == true)` this line is never executed. If you are grounded, you always have _extraJumps > 1.  You could always allow the jump as long as the counter is higher than 0 (as in the condition before). And your hit ladder logic is a bit flawed, since you do not handle what you want to do when both keys are pressed. Or of you release space after jumping but hit the ladder

Comment: I noticed that you effectively rolled back my edits that corrected grammar errors & removed excess line breaks in the code block. My edits were an attempt to improve your question with regards to readability & [community norms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25/228147). I'd genuinely like to understand why you removed my corrections.

Comment: Hey pikalek....sry, the question i wrote earlier was not properly expalained ...so i editted my question....actually i am not very good at english and i am still learning unity....thank you for your correction and plz keep help us if we wrong somthing..

Comment: @mackFire It's okay, the editing system can be confusing to new users & I can understand the outcome given the circumstances. Bear in mind that the presentation of your question can influence how well the community responds to it. Others may edit to improve it after you post, but it's better if you can make a good first impression.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I totally understand your `ladder` and `jump` interaction. If the behaviour you want is different from this, I will adjust it. The basic idea behind this is, you can't climb the ladder if you do not have any jumps. Since jumps refill when we are on the ground, you can always start climbing up and down from the platform. But when jumping, there is no interaction with the ladder (at least not now if your maxjumpamount is only 1)

```
if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && _extraJumps > 0) {
  _rb.velocity = new Vector2(_rb.velocity.x,_jumpForce);
  _extraJumps --;
}

RaycastHit2D hitLadder = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position,Vector2.up,_distance,_ladderLayer);

if(hitLadder.collider && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && _extraJumps > 0) {
  _rb.gravityScale = 0;
  _rb.velocity = new Vector2(_rb.velocity.x,_verticalMovement * _ySpeed);
} else {
  _rb.gravityScale = 1;
}
```